# リダイレクト先のHTML(OGP)をSwiftで取得したい

Tags: swift

https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/comments/x4uthz/help_im_trying_to_save_blobs_using_tss_saver_on/ にリダイレクトされるようなURL(https://redd.it/x4uthz)があり、このURL(https://redd.it/x4uthz)しか知らない状態でSwiftでリダイレクト先のHTML(OGP)を取得したいのですがどのようにすれば良いでしょうか？